# Incorrect syntax near 'Ordertb'

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, updates

I want to refresh and update gridview so I use showData() like this:

```
protected void ShowData()
{
    con.Open();
    string qu = string.Format("SELECT * Ordertb", con);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(qu, con);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds, "ordertbl");
    if (ds.Tables["ordertbl"].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        GridView1.DataSourceID = null;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
    con.Close();
}
```

but I get this error:

```
Incorrect syntax near 'Ordertb'.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near 'Ordertb'.
```

Comment: Have you tried running the query in management studio ? Looks like you are missing a from `SELECT * FROM Ordertb'

Comment: you right. thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It looks like you're missing the keyword 'from' before Ordertb.

```
string qu = string.Format("SELECT * FROM Ordertb", con);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this SQL query:

```
Select * From Ordertb
```

In your code:

```
string qu = string.Format("Select * From Ordertb", con);
```